# read the some data in txt file and pass it to string array

Tags: c++

I use VS2010 in windows 7 to write C++ mfc program. I want to read a txt file by line and pass it to the string array.

I have tried the testByLine function but it says name "fstream" is unidentified.Also, "ios::in" seems incorrect in my windows 7 but I do not know how to correct it.

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>

std::string Value_2[5];

void testByLine()
{
    char buffer[256];
    fstream outFile;
    outFile.open("result.txt", ios::in);
    int i = 0;
    while (!outFile.eof()) {

        outFile.getline(buffer, 128, '\n');
        Value_2[i] = buffer;
        i += 1;
    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

I expected every line in the txt being passed to  each element of string array  Value_2.

Comment: You're missing `std::` in front of fstream.

Comment: Also [beware your while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: use [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) for reading

Comment: [Your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to have a chat about the unchanging value of `i`

Comment: See [`why `eof()` in a loop condition is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    std::string read;
    std::string arr[5];
    std::ifstream outFile;
    outFile.open("test.txt");

    int count = 0;

    //reading line by line 
    while(getline(outFile, read)){

        //add to arr
        arr[count] = read;
        count++;
    }

    outFile.close();

    //c++ 11
    // for(std::string str : arr) std::cout << str << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```